# Phoenix: How to broadcast event to a different channel?

Tags: sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm making an app that matches 2 users. I'm trying to use `socket.assigns` to store the email of Person B to Person A's socket, and vice versa.

When person A makes the request to the channel, I can update the socket without a problem with `assign(socket, :matched_client_email, "personB@email.com")` . However, I don't know how to broadcast to Person B's channel so that I can call `assign(socket, :matched_client_email, "personA@email.com")`

```
  def handle_in("find_match", %{ "app" => app }, socket) do
    ...

      push socket, "match_found", %{
        email: matched_user.email,
        first_name: first_name(matched_user.name),
        profile_image: matched_user.profile_image,
      }

      VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
        "user_pool:#{matched_user.email}",
        "match_found",
        %{
          email: current_user.email,
          first_name: first_name(current_user.name),
          profile_image: current_user.profile_image,
        }
      )
    ...

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  # never gets called
  def handle_out("match_found", %{ "email" => email }, socket) do
    Logger.info("HEREEEE #{email}")
    assign(socket, :matched_client_email, email)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

How would I broadcast an event to Person B from Person A's channel so that the `handle_in` method is called?

Comment: Do you have a call to [`Phoenix.Channel.intercept/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#intercept/1) in the module?

Comment: oooo didn't know about that, let me try it out

Comment: Would you by any chance know the difference between `handle_in` and `handle_out`?

Comment: it worked!!!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`Phoenix.Channel.intercept/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#intercept/1) with a list of events you want `handle_out` to be called for. In your case, you should add this:

```
intercept ["match_found"]
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation? Why does this solve the problem?